# Subtracting coordinates to get a parallel vector

Tags: vectors

Consider the vectors W, X, Y and Z in R<sup>3</sup>, Where w = (3,2,6) and x = (4, 6, 8). We have to find **WX**(WX vector, not bold text is used instead of the arrow head), So, using the triangular law we take **OX**-**OW** to get: **WX** = (1, 4, 2). Taking this digrammatically:
[image]

So, How do we get a vector, say **L**, with it's head point at (1, 4, 2), which is exactly parallel to **WX**?
[image]
(Note that I have presented the diagrams in a sort of planar form, even though the vectors are in spaces).

Comment: Am I understanding your question correctly as "how to draw the on the diagram ${\bf OL}$ vector, such as OL=WX and the two are parallel?"

Comment: @Andrei, I actually have found it very hard to put my dilemma into words. What I mean is we take two points in space and use the triangle law to find the wx vector, and gain a new vector which is parallel to wx vector, and is completely apart from wx vector, but is parallel to it. If so what is the significance of finding wx vector in the first place?

Comment: What is the meaning of finding wx vector between the two points w and x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider all your vectors in this case as "difference" vectors ${\bf OW}=(3,2,6)-(0,0,0)$, ${\bf OX}=(4,6,8)-(0,0,0)$, so then ${\bf WX}=(4,6,8)-(3,2,6)$. The length and direction of ${\bf WX}$ is the same as for ${\bf OL}$, but ${\bf OL}$ is the "difference" from origin ${\bf OL}=(1,4,2)-(0,0,0)$. The only distinction between ${\bf WX}$ and ${\bf OL}$ is the origin, so in many cases the two will be interchangeable.

Comment: the question again is: we are actually using the coordinates of W and X but are getting a new coordinate upon subtraction, which when drawn as a position vector(or difference vector) from the origin is equal to wx vector(both in mag. and dir.). We can see that this is true, but is there a proof for this?(As an analogy, we can see that digits after decimals for the value of pie{3.14......} are irrational, but a proof is not there.)

Comment: I think you made a mistake there: "OX = (4,6,8) - (3,2,6)", should be (0,0,0)

Comment: you are right. I will make the change

Comment: As to why they are equal, you can draw a quadrilateral OLXW, and show that it  is a parallelogram

Comment: I think I get it, do analyze the post I've given.

Answer (score 0):

When we are subtracting the coordinates of P from Q, we are taking the units along each axis, therefore, this would obviously be equal to the vector taken from the origin.
Another way to interpret is that, subtraction actually gives the slope, and thus the slope being equal makes the vector parallel.